# Centering multiple images horizontally with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The issue I'm encountering is when I add four images to the `.images` container the `justify-content:center` property which I am applying to center up the images horizontally on page does not work.

However when I only have two images inside the `.images` container I get the images horizontally centered.

I've been able to find a solution to centering the images up horizontally by using the `text-align` property on the `.images` container. This feels slightly like a hack though.

[**CODE PEN**](http://codepen.io/kapena/pen/ZQKvve)

#### HTML

```
<div class="proj_images">
    <div class="images">
        <img class="disp1" src="http://placehold.it/450x350.png" alt="">
        <img class="disp2" src="http://placehold.it/450x350.png" alt="">
        <img class="disp3" src="http://placehold.it/450x350.png" alt="">
        <img class="disp4" src="http://placehold.it/450x350.png" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.proj_images{
    display: flex;
    width:100%;

}

.images{
 text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: The `justify-content:center;` you commented out seems to work for me. BTW `//` isn't valid CSS comment syntax. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dGWJjQ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aside from the solution that you already have, you could also set the `display` of the `.images` element to `flex`, and then add `justify-content: center` along with `flex-wrap: wrap`.

When you set `justify-content: center` on the `.proj_images` element, that was only centering the children flexbox items (which would be `.images` and not the descendant `img` elements). Which is why you would need to set those properties/values on the direct parent of the `img` elements (so that the `img` elements themselves are flexbox items).

```css
.images {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="proj_images">
  <div class="images">
    <img class="disp1" src="http://placehold.it/250x150.png" alt="">
    <img class="disp2" src="http://placehold.it/250x150.png" alt="">
    <img class="disp3" src="http://placehold.it/250x150.png" alt="">
    <img class="disp4" src="http://placehold.it/250x150.png" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great answer @Josh and thank you for the explanation. I had previously tried to make the `img` elements flex items by adding `display:flex` to `.images` but I realize now is that I was also missing was the `flex-wrap:wrap` property. I was just doing `display:flex` `justify-content:center` and was not seeing the images centered up. When adding the `flex-wrap` property everything becomes centered.

Answer (score 3):

When you create a flex container (by applying `display: flex` or `display: inline-flex` to an element), the *child elements* become flex items. The descendants of the flex container beyond the children do not become flex items and, therefore, do not accept flex properties.

When you make `.proj_images` a flex container, flex properties apply to a singular flex item: `.images`. To apply flex properties to the four images, add `display: flex` to `.images`.

Also, when you establish a flex container, several default rules go into effect. Two of these rules are `flex-direction: row` and `flex-wrap: nowrap`. If you want the images to align vertically or to wrap, you'll need to override these defaults with `flex-direction: column` and `flex-wrap: wrap`.

For more details on centering flex items horizontally (and vertically), see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33049198/3597276