# having some layout issues with Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am playing around with flexbox but still running into some issues.. I almost have what I want:

1. label in Top left of first container
2. label in Top right of first container
3. Label in bottom middle of first container
4. box that has "number" on top of "Label"
5. text in center area.
6. Have multiple of these on one line(I have not done this yet, right now if I made another it would be it's own line).

Problems

1. Would like spacing between green box and blue box. Tried to use "space-around" but it does not seem to do what I want. I also would like the containers to be the same size but not sure how to do that so it would be responsive.
2. Would like the text in the center to actually be center of itself as well not just the "p" tag.
3. Would like to have it on bigger screens that more than one container fits on a line. Not sure if I need to wrap another flex container around it.
4. Spacing between the root containers.

```css
.flex-container {

  display: flex;

  flex-direction: column;

  background-color: grey;

  padding: 0;


}

.flex-sub-container {

  display: flex;

  flex-direction: row;

  justify-content: space-between;

}

.flex-item-left-corner {

  /*background-color: red;*/

  margin: 0;

  padding: 0;

}

.flex-item-right-corner {

  /*background-color: red;*/

  margin: 0;

  padding: 0;

  justify-content: flex-end;

}

.flex-bottom-middle {

  /*background-color: red;*/

  align-self: center;

  margin: 0;

}

.flex-sub-container2 {

  /*background-color: yellow;*/

  display: flex;

  flex-direction: row;

  justify-content: center;

}

.flex-sub-item {

  background-color: green;

  display: flex;

  flex-direction: column;

  align-items: center;

  flex-grow: 1;

}

.flex-qty {

  margin: 0;

  font-size: 28pt;

}

.flex-qty-label {

  margin: 0 5pt 5pt 5pt;

}

.flex-center {

  background-color: royalblue;

  align-self: center;

  font-size: 15pt;

  flex-grow: 3;

}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container card-panel teal lighten-2">
  <div>
    <div class="flex-sub-container">
      <p class="flex-item-left-corner">Left Top</p>
      <p class="flex-item-right-corner">Right Top</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="flex-sub-container2">
      <div class="flex-sub-item">
        <p class="flex-qty">7</p>
        <p class="flex-qty-label">Label</p>
      </div>
      <p class="flex-center">This is my very long center text.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p class="flex-bottom-middle">Bottom Middle</p>
</div>

<div class="flex-container card-panel teal lighten-2">
  <div>
    <div class="flex-sub-container">
      <p class="flex-item-left-corner">Left Top</p>
      <p class="flex-item-right-corner">Right Top</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="flex-sub-container2">
      <div class="flex-sub-item">
        <p class="flex-qty">7</p>
        <p class="flex-qty-label">Label</p>
      </div>
      <p class="flex-center">This is my very long center text.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p class="flex-bottom-middle">Bottom Middle</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have an image of what this is supposed to look like? It's much better than a "word picture".

Comment: Do you mean something like this - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/dMorKg

Comment: yes, I think that covers all my problems(I have not checked on smaller screen). Step 6 is still outstanding. On my large screen here I would like to see both these master containers on same line. Could you highlight what you changed?

Comment: As you said, you can add a flex-container but you would still need media queries for that.

Comment: Ah, can't make it without a media query?  Thought that if there would be no space or something on smaller screens and it would just push it to one per row on smaller devices.

Comment: You can try it without media queries, it's not impossible but flexbox isn't magic..it does occasionally need some help.

Comment: If I use media queries would it be just removing the class on smaller screens vs bigger screens or would I have to have 2 separate structures?

Comment: No you can probably do it with the same structure but you'd have to adjust the flex values depending on the media query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would like spacing between green box and blue box. Tried to use "space-around" but it does not seem to do what I want.

Just added some margin between them. The `space`options only work if there is actual space there...i.e. the sum of the child widths is less than the parent width.

> I also would like the containers to be the same size but not sure how to do that so it would be responsive.
>
> Would like the text in the center to actually be center of itself as well not just the "p" tag.

Wrapped the `p` in  div which makes the two divs equal height and then centered the text as usual

> Would like to have it on bigger screens that more than one container fits on a line. Not sure if I need to wrap another flex container around it.

As you said, you can add a flex-container (with wrapping) but you would still need to add media queries as relevant.

> Spacing between the root containers.

Just `margin-bottom`

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.flex-sub-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.flex-item-left-corner {
  /*background-color: red;*/
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.flex-item-right-corner {
  /*background-color: red;*/
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.flex-bottom-middle {
  /*background-color: red;*/
  align-self: center;
  margin: 0;
}
.flex-sub-container2 {
  /*background-color: yellow;*/
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.flex-sub-item {
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.flex-qty {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 28pt;
}
.flex-qty-label {
  margin: 0 5pt 5pt 5pt;
}
.flex-center {
  background-color: royalblue;
  font-size: 15pt;
  flex: 3;
  margin-left: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container card-panel teal lighten-2">
  <div>
    <div class="flex-sub-container">
      <p class="flex-item-left-corner">Left Top</p>
      <p class="flex-item-right-corner">Right Top</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="flex-sub-container2">
      <div class="flex-sub-item">
        <p class="flex-qty">7</p>
        <p class="flex-qty-label">Label</p>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-center">
        <p>This is my very long center text.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p class="flex-bottom-middle">Bottom Middle</p>
</div>

<div class="flex-container card-panel teal lighten-2">
  <div>
    <div class="flex-sub-container">
      <p class="flex-item-left-corner">Left Top</p>
      <p class="flex-item-right-corner">Right Top</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>

    <div class="flex-sub-container2">

      <div class="flex-sub-item">
        <p class="flex-qty">7</p>
        <p class="flex-qty-label">Label</p>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-center">
        <p>This is my very long center text.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <p class="flex-bottom-middle">Bottom Middle</p>
</div>
```