# How to put images side by side in html

Tags: html, image

I'm pretty new to html/css and I've looked around for hours but can't seem to make these images line up side by side. My idea is to make a lobby for a game and I want to display all of the players side by side along with their names below them, although all I ask is how to get these images to line up horizontally. Then I will worry about putting text beneath them later.
HTML:

```
  <div class= = "container">
<div class = "row">
  <div class = "column" id = "player1" style = "visibility:visible" >
    <img src = "PlayerPicture.png" style = "width:auto">
  </div>
  <div class = "column" id = "player2" style = "visibility:visible" >
    <img src = "PlayerPicture.png" style = "width:auto">
  </div>
  <div class = "column" id = "player3" style = "visibility:visible" >
    <img src = "PlayerPicture.png" style = "width:auto">
  </div>
  <div class = "column" id = "player4" style = "visibility:visible" >
    <img src = "PlayerPicture.png" style = "width:auto">
  </div>
  <div class = "column" id = "player5" style = "visibility:visible" >
    <img src = "PlayerPicture.png" style = "width:auto">
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: How the image looks with the code above]

Comment: `.column{
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    padding: 5px;
}

.row::after{
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}`

Im not sure how to post more code, this is my css right here.
Thank you to anyone in advanced!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Centering multiple images horizontally with flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34685417/centering-multiple-images-horizontally-with-flexbox)

Answer (score 0):

please try to add this code in your CSS might work for you

.row { display: flex;}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: omg thank you so much! This took me like 6 hours of researching and I can't believe this is all it took. Much love!